# solving integral equation, differentiation method

Tags: derivatives, integral-equations

I have trouble with solving Volterra integral equation by using differentiation method

$\varphi(x)=x-\int_0^x e^{x-t}\varphi(t)dt.$

[picture of task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVJzt.png)

so, I guess I need to find derivative of $\varphi(x)$, but what's next? Can you please help with algorithm. 
I also have problems with finding derivative of integral. Can you tell how this is done?

The answer of the task is $\varphi(x) =  x - \frac{x^2}{2}$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the desired expression as 
$$\phi(x)e^{-x} = xe^{-x} - \int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}\phi(t)$$ 
Differentiating both sides, we get 
$$e^{-x}((\phi(x))'-\phi(x)) = e^{-x}(1-x)-e^{-x}\phi(x)$$
$$\therefore (\phi(x))'-\phi(x) = 1-x - \phi(x)$$
$$\therefore (\phi(x))'= 1-x$$
From this, 
$$\phi(x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2} + C$$ where C is some constant which can be found by putting $x=0$ in the initial expression
$$\therefore \phi(x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!